# Cross-references between two papers

Tags: cross-referencing, links

It is something I already did in the past, several years ago, and I can't remember how I proceeded. I have a directory with two tex files which will be never merged. So I have something like paper1.tex, paper1.bib, paper2.tex, paper2.bib, etc... I would like to use paper1's theorems/propositions/definitions in paper2. paper1 is not finished. So the numbering in paper1 may change a lot.

Example: I have Theorem~2.8 in paper1 that I want to use in paper2 in `\cite[Theorem~2.8]{paper1}`. After modifying paper1, Theorem~2.8 becomes Theorem~3.5 and I would like that `\cite[Theorem~2.8]{paper1}` in paper2 automatically becomes `\cite[Theorem~3.5]{paper1}`.

Comment: you seem to be referring to `\label`/`\ref` of theorems, for which you can use the `xr` package but I'm confused by your mention of `bbl` which I would not have expected to be involved?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ah, that excellent `xr` package again....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think it's the package I need indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- but `xr` apparently cannot be used together with `hyperref`, or so it says in the *companion*.  the `xr` documentation says no such thing, but it's still got a 1994 date.  please update!

Comment: This package is really excellent indeed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Isn't `xr-hyper` meant to provide the `hyperref` compatibility for this then?

Comment: @barbarabeeton hyperref comes with a modified version (xr-hyper)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- maybe so, but i had to dig into this yesterday, and the only documentation i could find was `xr.pdf` from 1994, and the overview in the *companion* which may well be out of date.  so an update *is* badly needed, if only to the documentation.  where can i find current documentation, please?  the hyperref documentation is what comes up when i ask for `xr-hyper`, but what it says about `xr` is pretty sketchy, and not enough to help us solve our current problem without digging into code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- good to know, but where is good documentation on how exactly to use it?  `texdoc xr-hyper` brings up the `hyperref` manual, which does mention changes for compatibility`, but when we try to process the file that calls for it, it crashes.  the `xr` documentation doesn't say, for example, that both documents have to be in the same area, or if they're not (our situation), how to indicate the location of the "other".  (let's take this off line.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton the user documentation for xr-hyper is same as that of xr, it just uses hyperref internals for the references instead of standard latex ones.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am using a symbolic link towards paper1.aux (linux); that works very well; paper1 and paper2 are not in the same directory actually.